# Dynamically alter an underscore template for Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone with underscore templates defined in my html like so:

```
<script type="text/template" id="editTemplate">
    <select id="scred" class="scredSelect">
        <!-- some options -->
    </select>
</script>
```

and assigned to my Backbone view template (via coffeescript) like this:

```
template: _.template $("#editTemplate").html()
```

everything is working as intended. However... I would like to dynamically add some options to the select `scred`.

I've tried to access the scred select via `$("#editTemplate").find('.scredSelect')`, but of course, since everything inside of the script tags is not treated as html, the selector doesn't work.

I can access the element like so...

```
html = $("#editTemplate").html()
$(html).find('.scredSelect').doStuff()
```

Is there an even easier way to accomplish this?  Or would this be a task better suited to a full blown templating engine like handlebars or mustache?

Comment: Is there any template stuff inside `#editTemplate` or is it just a piece of static HTML? You could make `template:` a function and then do whatever needs to be done inside that function.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, there are `<%= Name %>` elements that are populated via my backbone model.

Comment: Any particular reason you can't populate all the `<option>`s from a model too?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, the dropdown is a list of customers, if there is a customer not in the list, I have a way to add a new customer.  This works perfectly and the new model is saved with the new customer, however, if someone wants to create another new model, the customer select does not contain the recently created customer unless the page is refreshed.  (If that makes sense).  I'm using a dropdown instead of an input, to ensure that spelling is consistent.

Comment: You can pass whatever data you want to a template, it doesn't have to be `model.toJSON()`, `template(model: model.toJSON(), customers: customers.toJSON())` for example.

Comment: Aha!  I think it just clicked!  Thanks!   Leaving work for the day, but I think I can tackle the problem now!